# terminate linux program when lines repeat endlessly

Tags: bash, awk, pipe, infinite-loop

A finance-crunching program I am dealing with, **cruncher.js**, has annoying bugs difficult to troubleshoot.  One common problem (whose triggering input is difficult to pointpoint and therefore avoid) causes this failure scenario:

```
Downloading account information...
Downloading today orders...
Downloading historical quotes...
Downloading historical quotes...
Downloading historical quotes...
Downloading historical quotes...
```

Once the line *"Downloading historical quotes..."* repeats for a third time, I know it's hit an infinite loop and never exits, nor skips whatever input case it can't handle gracefully.

How can I pipe this cruncher.js program to **|awk**, i.e. what inline awk script would detect in its input a 3rd (or 2nd if much easier) consecutive repeated line, and terminate there?

Or maybe instead of awk, using other common Linux/shell tools?

Comment: From another perspective, can you limit on time? because then you would have ready built tools like `timeout 100s command` that already exists.

Comment: Yeah, I already do that, timeout 6m crappyScript.js . Only as a stop-gap measure to prevent a server crisis.  It's already at the maximum reasonable before being too much time wasted stuck on this bug, while sometimes legitimate runs need more time than that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way

```
$ yes | awk -v key='y' '{if($0==key)c++; else c=0} c==3{exit}1' 
y
y
```

replace the key value with your repeated value; and `yes` with your stream generator.